# Best Way to get numbers value decoded as unicode python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

Is there a better way to get unicode string from number value than
`str(value).decode('utf-8')`?

Example Usage :

```
from scipy.io import wavfile

encoding = 'utf-8'
def get_data(basename):
        print (basename).decode(encoding)
        sampFreq, snd  = wavfile.read(basename+'.wav')
        print (u'sample freq: ' + str(sampFreq).decode(encoding) + ' Hz')
        print (u'sample size: '+ str(snd.dtype).decode(encoding))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`unicode()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) directly:

```
print u'sample freq: ' + unicode(sampFreq) + u' Hz'
print u'sample size: '+ unicode(snd.dtype)
```

or pass the values separately to `print` (it'll convert every part to a string add spaces between):

```
print u'sample freq:', sampFreq, u'Hz'
print u'sample size:', snd.dtype
```

but best practice is to use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (really `unicode.format()` here):

```
print u'sample freq: {} Hz'.format(sampFreq)
print u'sample size: {}'.format(snd.dtype)
```

See the [*Format String Syntax* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to decode, `str()` is sufficient, i.e.

```
print (u'sample freq: ' + str(sampFreq) + ' Hz')
print (u'sample size: '+ str(snd.dtype))
```

will work, however, this:

```
print(u'sample freq: {} Hz'.format(sampFreq))
print(u'sample size: {}'.format(snd.dtype))
```

which uses [**`str.format()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format), is the "modern"/preferable way to do it.

Comment: My guess is using `str` is the wrong converter, so there is implicit conversion to `unicode` as well.  Also, `unicode.format()` is being used in the second case.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Maybe, but it's not really incorrect if you know that it will end up unicode anyway. Using `str()` in this way makes this code Python 3 compatible, not an immediate requirement, but a worthwhile aim. And `unicode.format()` is basically the same as `str.format()` AFAICT. But thanks!